# friends_who_tagged returns empty data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the list of friends who were at a particular place.

For the Bellagio in Las Vegas I use this to get the context ID:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/83005907820?fields=context
```

I then do this to get the list of friends (User nodes) who were tagged there:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/b3Blbl9ncmFwaF9jb250ZAXh0OjgzMDA1OTA3ODIw/friends_tagged_at
```

The problem I have is that I only get this in the response:

```
{ 
  data: [ ],
  summary: {
    total_count: 1
  }
}
```

I'm using an access token which I got from the Graph API Explorer with all the permissions selected.

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only friends who authorized your App will show up in that list, for privacy reasons. I assume that one friend is tagged at the specific place, but he did not authorize your App.

Comment: Got it. I was trying this on the Graph API Explorer so I could only get the users who gave permission to that app.